# What is a secure approach for storing an encryption key to use in 2 different applications?

Tags: asp.net, .net, encryption

I have 2 fields that I need to encrypt in a SQL Server database, a password and an ID number. I'm thinking on Rijndael and I've already got the scripts to encrypt/decrypt and will use machinekey for the public key.

The ID number will have to be able to be decrypted from 2 different apps, a web app and a console app that live in the same server.

What approach should I take for the machinekey? Should I create one using a tool like this one:

http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Or should I just autogenerate them in the 2 apps web.config files as:

```
<machineKey  validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps"  decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
```

What's more secure? Or is there a more secure way? I read something about DPAPI which uses the actual machine's key?

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't encrypt password field. Encrypting password is bad, someone gaining access to the key can decrypt all of your passwords so use Hashing. The algorithm you use for hashing i recommend should be bcrypt.

Secondly for encryption of ID use AES 256 bit algorithm and for storing encryption keys use microsoft solution that uses cryptoutility component which uses DPAPI (see:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163884.aspx). Donot store keys in the code anyone having the access to code can find that key and also you won't have any auditing capabilities related to who accessed the key and changed. Also storing in-process dll is bad that presents several security risks.